# In Java 8 how do I transform a Map<K,V> to another Map<K,V> using a lambda?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've just started looking at Java 8 and to try out lambdas I thought I'd try to rewrite a very simple thing I wrote recently.  I need to turn a Map of String to Column into another Map of String to Column where the Column in the new Map is a defensive copy of the Column in the first Map.  Column has a copy constructor.  The closest I've got so far is:

```
    Map<String, Column> newColumnMap= new HashMap<>();
    originalColumnMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(x -> newColumnMap.put(x.getKey(), new Column(x.getValue())));
```

but I'm sure there must be a nicer way to do it and I'd be grateful for some advice.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

You could use a [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Defensive {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Column> original = new HashMap<>();
    original.put("foo", new Column());
    original.put("bar", new Column());

    Map<String, Column> copy = original.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                  e -> new Column(e.getValue())));

    System.out.println(original);
    System.out.println(copy);
  }

  static class Column {
    public Column() {}
    public Column(Column c) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the important (and slight counter-intuitive) thing to note in the above is that the transformation takes place in the collector, *rather* than in a map() stream operation

Comment: Yeah I was hoping it could be done outside the collector. It feels different to other types of transforms.

Comment: The Java functional API is horribly ugly for sure

Answer (score 34):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("test1", 1);
map.put("test2", 2);

Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach(map2::put);

System.out.println("map: " + map);
System.out.println("map2: " + map2);
// Output:
// map:  {test2=2, test1=1}
// map2: {test2=2, test1=1}
```

You can use the `forEach` method to do what you want.

What you're doing there is:

```
map.forEach(new BiConsumer<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String s, Integer integer) {
        map2.put(s, integer);     
    }
});
```

Which we can simplify into a lambda:

```
map.forEach((s, integer) ->  map2.put(s, integer));
```

And because we're just calling an existing method we can use a [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which gives us:

```
map.forEach(map2::put);
```

Comment: I like how you've explained exactly what's going on behind the scenes here, it makes it much clearer.  But I think that just gives me a straight copy of my original map, not a new map where the values have been turned into defensive copies.  Am I understanding you correctly that the reason we can just use (map2::put) is that the same arguments are going into the lambda, e.g. (s,integer) as are going into the put method?  So to do a defensive copy would it need to be `originalColumnMap.forEach((string, column) ->  newColumnMap.put(string, new Column(column)));` or could I shorten that?

Comment: Yes you are. If you're just passing in the same arguments you can use a method reference, however in this case, since you have the `new Column(column)` as a paremeter, you'll have to go with that.

Comment: I like this answer better because it works if both maps are already provided to you, such as in session renewal.

Comment: Not sure to understand the point of such an answer. It is rewriting the constructor of mostly all Map implementations from an existing Map - like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-).

Answer (score 22):

Keep it Simple and use Java 8:-

```
 Map<String, AccountGroupMappingModel> mapAccountGroup=CustomerDAO.getAccountGroupMapping();
 Map<String, AccountGroupMappingModel> mapH2ToBydAccountGroups = 
              mapAccountGroup.entrySet().stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getValue().getH2AccountGroup(),
                                                   e ->e.getValue())
                                  );
```

Comment: in this case:map.forEach(map2::put); is simple :)

Answer (score 14):

<s>The way without re-inserting all entries into the new map should be the fastest</s> it won't because `HashMap.clone` internally performs rehash as well.

```
Map<String, Column> newColumnMap = originalColumnMap.clone();
newColumnMap.replaceAll((s, c) -> new Column(c));
```

Comment: That's a very readable way to do it and quite concise.  It looks like as well as HashMap.clone() there's `Map<String,Column> newColumnMap =  new HashMap<>(originalColumnMap);`.  I don't know if it's any different under the covers.

Comment: This approach has the advantage of keeping the `Map` implementation’s behavior, i.e. if `Map` is an `EnumMap` or a `SortedMap`, the resulting `Map` will be as well. In case of a `SortedMap` with a special `Comparator` it might make a huge semantic difference. Oh well, the same applies to an `IdentityHashMap`…

Answer (score 7):

If you use Guava (v11 minimum) in your project, you can use [Maps::transformValues](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Function-).

```
Map<String, Column> newColumnMap = Maps.transformValues(
  originalColumnMap,
  Column::new // equivalent to: x -> new Column(x) 
)
```

Note: The values of this map are evaluated lazily. If the transformation is expensive, you can copy the result to a new map like suggested in the Guava docs.

> To avoid lazy evaluation when the returned map doesn't need to be a view, copy the returned map into a new map of your choosing.

Comment: Note: According to the docs, this returns a lazy evaluated view on the originalColumnMap, so the function Column::new is reevaluated each time the entry is accessed (which may not be desirable when the mapping function is expensive)

Comment: Correct. If the transformation is expensive you are probably fine with the overhead of copying that to a new map like suggested in the docs.`To avoid lazy evaluation when the returned map doesn't need to be a view, copy the returned map into a new map of your choosing.`

Comment: True, but it might be worth adding as a footnote in the answer for those who tend to skip reading the docs.

Comment: @Erric Makes sense, just added.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way that gives you access to the key and the value at the same time, in case you have to do some kind of transformation.

```
Map<String, Integer> pointsByName = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> maxPointsByName = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Double> gradesByName = pointsByName.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
                entry.getKey(), ((double) entry.getValue() /
                        maxPointsByName.get(entry.getKey())) * 100d))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing this, but am not thrilled about it.

Answer (score 2):

From Java 9 onwards it is even easier to do the transformation within the `map` part of the stream. Is was already possible to use a `new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` but the Map interface has an additional static method `Map.entry` which can also create an entry which can be used for this usecase.

### Java 9+

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Column> x;
        Map<String, Column> y = x.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> Map.entry((entry.getKey(), new Column(entry.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using 3rd party libraries, my [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) lib has extensions for all [JDK Collection](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/extending-jdk-8-collections-8ae8d43dd75e#.j5lxtrqze) types, including [Map](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/cyclops-react/1.0.0-RC1/com/aol/cyclops/data/collections/extensions/standard/MapX.html). You can directly use the map or bimap methods to transform your Map. A MapX can be constructed from an existing Map eg.

```
  MapX<String, Column> y = MapX.fromMap(orgColumnMap)
                               .map(c->new Column(c.getValue());
```

If you also wish to change the key you can write

```
  MapX<String, Column> y = MapX.fromMap(orgColumnMap)
                               .bimap(this::newKey,c->new Column(c.getValue());
```

bimap can be used to transform the keys and values at the same time.

As MapX extends Map the generated map can also be defined as

```
  Map<String, Column> y
```