# Convert a Map<String, List<String>> to Map<String, Object[]>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there a better way to convert a `Map<String, List<String>>` to `Map<String, Object[]>` or vice versa other than a for loop?
By better, I mean using any library or Lambda expressions

Comment: Please define "*better*" in the context of your requirements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. Can you now show what you have tried and describe why it doesn't achieve what you want? And have you done any research (like reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/22742974/1945631 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9572795/1945631)?

Comment: I have used the link provided by you to form an answer. I have posted the answer for this. I was wondering if this can be further improved?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this way as mentioned in [In Java 8 how do I transform a Map to another Map using a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742974/in-java-8-how-do-i-transform-a-mapk-v-to-another-mapk-v-using-a-lambda)

```
final Map<String, List<String>> listMap = new HashMap<>();
listMap.put("Dog", Arrays.asList("Boxer","Julie"));
listMap.put("Cat", Arrays.asList("Cat1","Cat2"));

Map<String,Object[]> objectMap = listMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey(), e->e.getValue().toArray()));
```

This worked.
Is there any issue with this code or can it be further improved?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a custom `Map` class that overrides the appropriate methods in the `java.util.Map` interface to handle "lazy" conversions.

Such a class would be initialized with the `Map<String, List<String>>` or `Map<String, Object[]>` object and operate as a native `Map<String, Object[]>` or `Map<String, List<String>>`, respectively.