# How to split a value in a map

Tags: java, hashmap

I am getting a map in the form as below :

```
{owner=sailpoint.object.Identity@2aea717c[id=8ad616906a065639016a0657e2df000d,name=Jsmith]}
```

How can I get only "Jsmith" as my value to key "owner"?

Comment: What type is your key? What you want to get as result?

Comment: Can you post your `HashMap` declaration?

Comment: So your map looks something like this: `Map<String, sailpoint.object.Identity>` and you would like a `Map<String, String>`? Then you could use streams, like so: `yourMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getName()));`

Comment: Your output show a `Identity` instance as a value, instead, use the `name` member of that instance as a value. (and of course, change the `Map` declaration. I don't believe we can write a correct answer to this question so I would propose to close for "typo" since you use the wrong value during the population of the map.

Comment: Following link should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742974/in-java-8-how-do-i-transform-a-mapk-v-to-another-mapk-v-using-a-lambda

Answer (score 0):

Value against owner key is an object. In your object `toString()` method you can return the `name`.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guys! I was able to solve this with: yourMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getName()));    THANKS LINO